# Application rejected iOS -- Confused in naming icon files

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios7, app-store

I recently uploaded an app to app store, had all the icon files as suggested by apple but my application was rejected because of repeating "icon" files, with different dimensions but same name. Below is the problem specification:

[image]

When I add an 80X80 icon image it asks me to rename it to icon~iphone, however that image is already present with dimensions 58X58. If there are two files with same name in my app package apple rejects my app. What is the solution? I am targeting iOS 7.1.

Comment: Why the negative vote? Please explain!!

Comment: Good practise: calling your icon files by naming their dimensions. So 120x120 would be icon120, 58x58 would be icon58 etc. Then add them to your project and set them as resources and you should be fine. Goodluck.

Comment: Can you elaborate on set them as resources? Do I need to reference these at some other place too? Please bear with me I am into Android and right now cleaning someone else's shit!

Comment: @user2822178, be strong but we all clean someone else's sh*t. :) I recommend you to read this: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html

Comment: I read that article, lots of useful info, cheers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First **remove all the icon files by deleting to trash** (not just delete references), now import the newly named files (like icon120, icon58, icon80 whatever you need) and click copy files with app target selected.

Now click the **map icons** to choose the right resources for your app icons.

The good thing about renaming the app icons is that there will be no mix up with other app icons that may linger in your xCode folder. You can now go to `Build Phases` and look at `Copy Bundle Resources`, where you can delete the old app icon files. If you can't find it, look at this screenshot (don't delete your new app icon files!):

[image: copyBundleresources]